# My container is not running while attach with MOUNT VOLUME

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've create volume like `docker volume create my-vol` in my machine. But when I run my container as follow:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=ppshein-test \
  --mount source=my-vol,destination=/var/www/ -p 3000:3000 \
  ppshein:latest
```

and found that my container is not working, that's why I've tried to logs

```
> sample-docker@1.0.0 start /var/www
> node index.js
```

and found as above. That's why I've tried to run that same image without attaching specific volume as follow:

```
docker run -d --restart=always -p 3001:3000 ppshein:latest
```

and found it's working smoothly. But I check its container logs and found as follow:

```
> sample-docker@1.0.0 start /var/www
> node index.js

Example app listening on port 3000!
```

Oddly, what I've found `Example app listening on port 3000!` of that last container even not found that same message on previous container.

Please let me know why. Thanks much.

Comment: You create volume __my-vol__ and next you try to mount __myvol2__ ? What does it mean it does not work? Also at first attempt you try to link port 3000 on host, maybe it's already occupied.

Comment: @KonradSitarz volume name is edited. I've used same volume name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that can be something you are looking for,
(from docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount))

> If you use --mount to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, Docker does not automatically create it for you, but generates an error.

Comment: damn, it's my careless mistake. thanks much. Problem is because I've mounted different volume name.